# Find Synonyms using Arabic Wordnet in java

Tags: java, arabic, wordnet, jaws-wordnet

I want to find synonyms using Arabic wordnet in java , I see this question before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28735706/find-synonyms-using-jaws-in-netbeans) ,  I used the same code source , but it didn't worked. Maybe because i'm using Arabic word net ?
I found also a lien http://javatutorialandprojects.blogspot.com/2012/10/finding-synonyms-and-hyponyms-for-words.html .
I'm getting an error message :

> Exception in thread "main" edu.smu.tspell.wordnet.impl.file.RetrievalException: Error opening index file: F:\TPRI2\AWN\lib\index.sense (Le chemin d’accès spécifié est introuvable)
>   This is the code source i used

```
    package lucene.ri;

import edu.smu.tspell.wordnet.NounSynset;
import edu.smu.tspell.wordnet.Synset;
import edu.smu.tspell.wordnet.SynsetType;
import edu.smu.tspell.wordnet.WordNetDatabase;

public class wordnet 
 {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String a[]=new String[2];
        int j=0;
        while(j<2)
        {
            System.setProperty("wordnet.database.dir", "F:\\TPRI2\\AWN\\lib");
            NounSynset nounSynset;
            NounSynset[] hyponyms;
            WordNetDatabase database = WordNetDatabase.getFileInstance();
            Synset[] synsets = database.getSynsets(a[j], SynsetType.NOUN);
             System.out.println("*********************************************");
            for (int i = 0; i < synsets.length; i++)
                {
            nounSynset = (NounSynset)(synsets[i]);
            hyponyms = nounSynset.getHyponyms();

            System.err.println(nounSynset.getWordForms()[0] +": " + nounSynset.getDefinition() + ") has " + hyponyms.length + " hyponyms");

                }
            j++;
        }
         System.out.println("*********************************************");
    }
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. We cant help you with your **code** problems ... when you do not show your **code** here.

Comment: And if my old french isn't too rusty, the message tells you that this file F:... index.sense could not be found. So, first thing: is that file really in that place?

Comment: GhostCat I pasted the code source

Comment: Please edit your question instead. You **never** provide more infos using answers or comments!

Comment: Thanks for the quick upvote; but again: please **delete** your answer with your code snippets; and maybe put that code *into* your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source code you are showing

```
  System.setProperty("wordnet.database.dir", "F:\\TPRI2\\AWN\\lib");
```

That means: **your** code is telling WordNet where to look for things. Thus: are you sure that the index file mentioned in that error message does really exist in that directly.

And as you now figured: that file is not there; well you have to search for it.

Maybe you are lucky and [this](https://github.com/dkpro/dkpro-lsr/issues/1) helps: check if there is a file sense.idx; and if so, rename (or create a copy) as index.sense

Comment: I didn't understand what should i do ?

Comment: I already told you: the MESSAGE complains about the fact that there is NO file named index.sense in that directory F:\... that your code points to. So the first thing is to check ... is that file in there?!

Comment: I also find this lien http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/363911-Access-Wordnet-Dictionary-with-JAWS/ , maybe it didn't work because i'm using Arabic wordnet instead of using wordnet ?